# Como se llama este efecto

Tags: html, css

Cordial Saludo.

Quiero saber como se llama este tipo de cosas para realizarlas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando voy digitando en el input, se despliega una especie de contenedor, ese diseño como se puede llamar para realizar uno similiar

Comment: Recibe el nombre de Autocomplete

Comment: Hola. Recuerda que las preguntas sin código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Agrega el código que tienes, por favor. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas como realizar una pregunta y evitar que te la cierren.

Comment: La pregunta es amplia y casi que basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su cierre, considerando tu reputación es una pregunta qué pudiste haber hecho en el [chat]

Comment: Tienes suficiente reputación para realizar este tipo de preguntas en [chat],saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se conoce como "**autocomplete**" que se deriva de un select de html donde las opciones son las que aparecen de forma dinámica, con ajax usualmente. Podrías decir que es una mezcla entre un input y un select de html.

Si quieres un término muy específico "**autocomplete con opciones desplegables**" no es un nombre muy catchy pero cualquier programador te entenderá si lo defines así.

En tu imagen aparece el diseño de google pero este puede tener cualquiera.

Aquí te dejo algunos ejemplos:

https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/demo/

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

https://community.algolia.com/places/

Comment: Gracias amigo, justo lo que buscaba